# Backbone Marionette CollectionView not rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I am going bonkers on this one. For some reason, my CollectionView is not rendering correctly, though the collection is being set correctly as a Backbone Collection, and though everything seems to indicate it should be working fine. In fact, when I log the object from the template, it even shows the correct attributes!

So why on earth is my region not showing the collection? Here's my code:

```
  merchants = @model.get("merchants")
  merchantsCollection = new MerchantsCollection()
  merchantsCollection.reset(merchants)

  storesview = new StoresView
    collection: merchantsCollection
    itemViewOptions: ->
      templateName: "image"
  storesview.render()
  console.dir merchantsCollection
  @storeResults.show storesview
  @trigger "panel:completed"
```

When I log the merchantsCollection, I get:

```
MerchantsCollection
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_listenerId: "l871"
length: 8
models: Array[8]
```

Here's my CollectionView code:

```
define [
  "backbone.marionette",
  "helpers",
  "global/views/store",
  "global/views/empty"
], (Marionette, helpers, StoreView, EmptyView) ->
  class StoresView extends Marionette.CollectionView

    className: "js-stores js-stores-view unstyled"
    tagName: "ul"
    itemView: StoreView
    emptyView: EmptyView

    initialize: (options) ->
      if options.template then @template = options.template
```

And my ItemView code:

```
define [
  "backbone.marionette",
  "global/models/store",
  'text!global/templates/store.html',
  'text!global/templates/store-image.html'
], (Marionette, storeModel, storeTemplate, storeImgTemplate) ->
  class StoreView extends Marionette.ItemView

    tagName   : 'li'
    className : "js-item store"
    template  : _.template storeTemplate

    events:
      "click a" : "gotoStore"

    collectionEvents:
      "all" : "render"

    initialize: (options) ->
      if options.templateName and options.templateName is "image"
        @template = _.template storeImgTemplate

    onRender: ->

    gotoCategory: (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: you dont need to call render on your view, when you call show on the veiw it this will call render on your view. is there any error on the console?

Comment: @Rayweb_on no errors in the console. I figured I didn't need to call render() like that. Strangely, it seems the object is getting passed down to the template but for some reason the CollectionView is not adding the elements into itself, nor is it being thrown into the view region (e.g. no empty <ul> tags)

Comment: I think the issue may be with the fact that you are passing a template to the StoresView( I think the same teamplate that you are using in the itemView "image") and this is not needed, and if it is this template is not acccesible in your Storesview as there is not !text declaration to get the template.

Comment: @Rayweb_on so I double checked and removed that call it still isn't quite working. Very confused.

Comment: You could add some debug call in your collection view to see if it is rendered but not placed in your DOM. Try to add a console.log @ call in you collectionsview's onShow or onRender method.

Comment: @Ingro that was the exact reason. Thank you!